# How to initialize an array in fortran from user input?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm new to fortran and I've been wrestling with this problem: I'd like to create and array in fortran that has a user defined size and shape.

In python, for example, I would just ask the user for the upper and lower limits of the array and then declare an array with those parameters. In fortran though, I have to first declare all the variables, including the array. And when declaring the array, I need to define the size/shape.

My first guess was to do something like this (I'll omit the begin/end parts):

```
INTEGER, parameter :: lower, upper
INTEGER, dimension(lower:upper) :: list
READ(*,*) lower, upper
WRITE(*,*) list
```

but this won't work, because the order of the declarations is wrong. The program wants me to first declare the array with it's size. I did try using the SHAPE/RESHAPE methods but didn't manage to get far with those. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, use allocatable arrays:

```
integer :: lower, upper
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: list

read(*,*) lower, upper
allocate(list(lower:upper))
list = ... something ...
write(*,*) list
```